# How to All post insert from one server to other server in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have posted some qualified data in wordpress live server and its same data post on other server in wordpress,is it possible from wordpress,if possible then how?

Comment: tools > import/export

Comment: without (tools > import/export) use,how possible?

Comment: Create a api for same or export and import the database

Comment: You can use the rest API, if you don't want to import/export

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for migrating WordPress posts/contents to one server(demo server) to another server(Live server)? If yes, you can use [DB Migrate Pro plugin](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/).

Answer (score 0):

Check this plugin : http://www.wpallimport.com/ for import and export